# What is the “conspiratorial anisotropy” if we would see no star redshifts in one direction of the sky?

Tags: cosmology, speed-of-light, space-expansion, redshift, one-way-speed-of-light

Suppose we see no redshift of stars in one direction only (or better, in directions on a small patch around it). And suppose in that direction (on a patch of sky around it) we see a lot more stars than in other directions. And suppose the redshift of the stars on the opposite side of the sky is more pronounced and the density of observed stars smaller than the other directions A possible explanation could be that the speed of light $c$ is infinite in one direction and half the normal $c$ in the opposite direction.

What would in this case be the conspiratorial anisotropy? Could we say, for example, that there is no expansion in the direction in which we see no redshift, while the density of stars is higher than elsewhere, and that in the opposite direction the expansion is faster and the star density is smaller than in other direction?

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about physics, since none of these hypothetical observations have been made, neither been predicted by a model.

Comment: @Koschi Well it's about the fact that we don't know if the speed of light is the same in two opposite directions. If you look to the stars though you would think you could see the difference. If it's infinite in one direction you would observe no redshift and in the opposite more of it. But we don't observe this. Does this mean the speed of light is the same in every direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observed redshift is simply a total redshift. You can arbitrarily decompose it into standard Doppler shift and the expansion of space. If the speed of light in infinite in one direction then there is no space expansion shift so the Doppler shift is higher and in the other direction the opposite happens.

Comment: So this can actually be the case?

Comment: Yes, it can. There is no observation that can possibly be inconsistent with a non-uniform one-way speed of light